# Display 2^40000 points in C# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create a 2 dimensional graph and display 2^40000 points on that graph. Now obviously displaying all of them at a time is not possible. Nobody would simply have that much memory. So, I want to display only certain points at a time say 2^7 or so and allow the panning facility so when the user pans, it would load and show next points.

So, questions are:

1) Is this possible in WinForms?

2) How can I get notified when the user pans the screen. Any code sample would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Using mouse or keyboard events.

Comment: thank god you posted that as comment and not answer :)

Comment: @Jack I think `MD.Unicorn` comment is a plausible answer to your question

Comment: @RedSerpent: Ok. I modified the question a bit. Hopefully now it doesn't deserve a yes and no type of answers. A bit description and a bit code would do no harm.

Comment: 2^40000? Is that number right? That's a LOT (as in, a LOT!) more than the number of atoms in the universe...

Comment: I understand you dont want to display all at the same time, but what is storing this dataset? This is still 2^39960 TB.

Comment: Yes, I'm curious to know what kind of data this number represents...

Comment: @Guillaume: All the info to recreate infinite multiverses ;p

Comment: @leppie Probably... And how can you extract 2^7 data out of 2^40000? It might take Lifetime of the universe^(lifetime of the universe) to read such an array of data...

Comment: Biggest problem would be to store that much amount. Think about possibility to split all points by regions, similair to how google map works. You have to maintain which regions are now shown, preload surrounding regions in background (similar to how Morrowind works, or how Minecraft preloads its chunks) and change current zero point (and as result do "panning", which may cause new regions to be load and old ones possibly released) via usual user interactions: keyboard, mouse, joystick, breanreader, L2hightecImplantPredictor, etc...

Comment: Perhaps it's really the XOR operator and not the power operator. It's C#, after all. ;)

Comment: I sensed some misreading or misunderstanding with that power-of-two, so I searched what problem domain had some magic number of 40000 and all I found was Warhammer40K..

Comment: Another fun fact... If you display a batch of 1^7 points every nanosecond, you will still need 2^39984 seconds to display all the points... Which is 2^39916 times the number of nanoseconds spanned since the universe exist... I still can't figure out what such a number means...

Comment: @Guillaume: Tape drive access would be measured in minutes ;p

Answer (score 0):

Using [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) is Possible

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;

namespace GraphTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly Fill _flip = new Fill(Color.White);
        private readonly PointPairList _mPointsListSample;
        private readonly GraphPane _myPane;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
            _myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Sample";
            _myPane.YAxis.Title.FontSpec.Size = 5f;
            _myPane.YAxis.Scale.FontSpec.Size = 5f;
            _myPane.XAxis.Scale.FontSpec.Size = 5f;
            _mPointsListSample = new PointPairList();

            _myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.Black, 45F);
            _myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.Black, 45F);

            _myPane.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            _myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
            _myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 7));


            _myPane.YAxis.Title.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Pink;
            _myPane.YAxis.Scale.Align = AlignP.Inside;
            _myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
            _myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 500;



        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var limit = new Random();
            bool flag = true;
            while (true)
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 7)); i++)
                    {
                        _mPointsListSample.Add(i, limit.Next(500));
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        DrawGraph();
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!flag)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 7) - 1); i++)
                        _mPointsListSample[i].Y = _mPointsListSample[i + 1].Y;
                    _mPointsListSample.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 7) - 1), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 7) - 1), limit.Next(500));
                    _mPointsListSample.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, 7)));
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    DrawGraph();
                }
            }
        }

        private void DrawGraph()
        {
            _myPane.CurveList.Clear();
            // Fabricate some data values 
            LineItem myCurve = _myPane.AddCurve("Sample", _mPointsListSample, Color.Red, SymbolType.Circle);
            myCurve.Symbol.Fill = _flip;
            myCurve.Line.IsVisible=false;
            zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it may help to plot all the values using 2D Graph,in Winform withrange as you expect 2^7.

Comment: Hes asking if its possible to draw the points while panning... Your answer draws everything at once which is not ideal for a set of 2^40000 points

Comment: Wow this code must be really performant with all those thread.Sleep() and Application.DoEvents(), ideal for this kind of scenario.

Comment: Is it comment useful or code is useful? yet nobody vote for the answer